# Upper limit of sequence involving the fractional part

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds, fractional-part

In  the survey "The Problems Submitted by Ramanujan to
the Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society",  the lower limit of the sequences $n\{n\sqrt 2\}, n\{n\sqrt 3\}$, where $\{\cdot\} $ is the frcational part function, are provided. I am wondering if  the upper limit of such sequences is equal to $+\infty?$

Comment: what is the general formula of the sequence? what is $n$ here?

Comment: Here $n$ is the variable of the  sequence. The first sequnce is defined by $u_n=n\{n\sqrt 2\}=n(n\sqrt 2 - [n\sqrt 2]), \forall n$, the second $v_n=n\{n\sqrt 3\}=n(n\sqrt 3 - [n\sqrt 3]), \forall n$,  where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

Comment: $n\{  n\sqrt{3} \}$ is a second sequence? And you want to find the bounds (lower limit, upper limit) of the general sequence $n\{  n\sqrt{p} \}$   where $p\in \mathbb{N}$ when $n\to +\infty$?

Comment: Yes, it is a second sequence.

Comment: Just the upper limit for $p=2$ and $p=3$. The lower limit is given in the above reference.

Answer (score 2):

The upper limit is $+\infty$ for the 2 sequences $(n\{n\sqrt{2}\})_n$ and $(n\{n\sqrt{3}\})_n$.

We study the first sequence (same method for the second sequence). As $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number, we can write it as
$$\sqrt{2} = \overline{1,a_0a_1a_2...a_k...}$$
where the sequence $(a_k)_k$ contains infinite non-zero elements (because $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number).

Suppose these non-zero numbers are $a_{\sigma(t)}$ where $\sigma(t)$ is an strictly increasing function in $\mathbb{N}+$.

Set $n = 10^{\sigma(t)}$, then the sub-sequence $(10^{\sigma(t)}\{10^{\sigma(t)}\sqrt{2}\})_t$ tends to $+\infty$, indeed
$$\begin{align}
10^{\sigma(t)}\{10^{\sigma(t)}\sqrt{2}\} &= 10^{\sigma(t)}\cdot \{1a_0a_1...a_{\sigma(t)-1} \color{red}{,}a_{\sigma(t)}a_{\sigma(t)+1}.... \}\\
&=10^{\sigma(t)}\cdot 0 \color{red}{,}a_{\sigma(t)}a_{\sigma(t)+1}....\\
&\ge 10^{\sigma(t)}\cdot 0.1 = 10^{\sigma(t)-1}\\
\end{align}$$

As $\sigma(t)$ is increasing, the sub-sequence $(10^{\sigma(t)}\{10^{\sigma(t)}\sqrt{2}\})_t$ tends to $+\infty$. Q.E.D

Comment: The argument is very clear. Thanks